# How $_POST value missing unless field specified within model rules?

Tags: php, yii2

Currently I have the following in my controller which when the form is submitted the post value of one of my fields return empty however if I assign a rule to that field and resubmit it return the proper value.

Does this error occur because I have the below in my controller?Try to validate all inputs and it causes an error because that field has no rules?

```
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $seo->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple([$model, $seo])) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the field as safe  in rules

a special validator aliased safe is provided so that you can declare an attribute to be safe without actually validating it. For example, the following rules declare that both title and description are safe attributes.

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
        [['your_field1', 'your_field2'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#safe-attributes